# What scope does <cfquery> initialize a variable to?

Tags: scope, coldfusion

What scope does `<cfquery>` use by default on a `.cfm` template? Will they be collected by the gc once a request ends?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default scope in `.cfm` is `VARIABLES`.

```
<cfquery name="x">
```

is equivalent to

```
<cfquery name="VARIABLES.x">
```

Not using the scope in front of a variable makes ColdFusion look for the variable in other scopes (starting with `VARIABLES` for the above case). There are exceptions based on the context, even in a `.cfm` template (local variables). You can learn more about it in the official docs, [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-coldfusion-variables/about-scopes.html)
 and [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/building-blocks-of-coldfusion-applications/building-and-using-coldfusion-components/cfc-variables-and-scope.html) It's worth knowing this.

And yes, when the request finishes, the variables are marked for garbage collection. You do not have to explicitly "delete" or "null" them.

Comment: I am going to take this one step farther. All variables by default are in the `variables.x` scope. And all such variables are GC'ed at the end of the request.

Comment: Strictly speaking, they're eligible for GC (if not referenced elsewhere) like Alex said. When they're actually GC'd is up to the jvm.